# DJango ORM double join with Sum

Tags: django

I searched for a similar case on SO and Google with no luck.

## SHORT EXPLANATION

I have transactions that belong to an account, and an account belongs to an account aggrupation.
I want to get a list of accounts aggrupations, with their accounts, and I want to know the total balance of each account (an account balance is calculated by adding all its transactions amount).

## LONG EXPLANATION

I have the following models (I include mixins for the sake of completeness):

```
class UniqueNameMixin(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('name'), max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class PercentageMixin(UniqueNameMixin):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    _validators = [MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)]

    current_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,
                                             decimal_places=2,
                                             validators=_validators,
                                             null=True,
                                             blank=True)

    ideal_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,
                                           decimal_places=2,
                                           validators=_validators,
                                           null=True,
                                           blank=True)


class AccountsAggrupation(PercentageMixin):
    pass


class Account(PercentageMixin):
    aggrupation = models.ForeignKey(AccountsAggrupation, models.PROTECT)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    concept = models.ForeignKey(Concept, models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, models.PROTECT)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} - {} - {}'.format(self.date, self.concept, self.amount, self.account)
```

I want to be able to do this in Django ORM:

```
select ca.*, ca2.*, sum(ct.amount)
from core_accountsaggrupation ca 
join core_account ca2 on ca2.aggrupation_id = ca.id 
join core_transaction ct on ct.account_id = ca2.id
group by ca2.name
order by ca.name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that nesting navigation through sets is not possible:

Wrong: `AccountsAggrupation.objects.prefetch_related('account_set__transaction_set')`

(or any similar approach). The way to work with this is the way around: go from transaction to account and then to account_aggroupation.

But, as I needed to have a dict with account_aggroupation, pointing each key to its set of accounts (and the balance for each), I ended up doing this:

```
def get_accounts_aggrupations_data(self):
    accounts_aggrupations_data = {}
    accounts_balances = Account.objects.annotate(balance=Sum('transaction__amount'))
    for aggrupation in self.queryset:
        aggrupations_accounts = accounts_balances.filter(aggrupation__id=aggrupation.id)
        aggrupation.balance = aggrupations_accounts.aggregate(Sum('balance'))['balance__sum']
        accounts_aggrupations_data[aggrupation] = aggrupations_accounts
    current_month = datetime.today().replace(day=1).date()
    date = current_month.strftime('%B %Y')
    total_balance = Transaction.objects.aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
    return {'balances': accounts_aggrupations_data, 'date': date, 'total_balance': total_balance}
```

Note that since I'm iterating through the accounts_aggrupations, that query (self.queryset, which leads to AccountsAggrupation.objects.all()) is executed to the DB.

The rest of the queries I do, do not execute yet because I'm not iterating through them (until consuming the info at the template).

Also note that the dictionary `accounts_aggrupations_data` has an accounts_aggrupation object as key.